# Connection Lost SocketCluster UWS + SSL NGINX

Tags: nginx, сокет, ssl

frontend не подключается к backend через SocketCluster

Config nginx

```
upstream backend {
   server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}


server { 
 listen 80; 
 server_name csgohill.ru; 
 access_log /var/log/csgohill.ru/nginx.access.log; 
 error_log /var/log/csgohill.ru/nginx.error.log; 
 root /var/www/apps/csgohill.ru/dist/; 
 charset utf-8; 

 location / { 
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent; 
 }

 location ~ /socketcluster/ {
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";    
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_read_timeout 30s;
       proxy_pass http://backend;
 }
} 

server { 
 listen 443 ssl; 
 server_name csgohill.ru;
 access_log /var/log/csgohill.ru/nginx.access.log; 
 error_log /var/log/csgohill.ru/nginx.error.log; 
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem; 
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem; 

 keepalive_timeout 5; 
 root /var/www/apps/csgohill.ru/dist/; 
 charset utf-8; 

 location ~ ^/(scripts.*js|styles|images) { 
   gzip_static on; 
   expires 1y; 
   add_header Cache-Control public; 
   add_header ETag ""; 
 }   

 location / { 
  try_files $uri /index.html$is_args$args;
 }

}


server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name socket.csgohill.ru;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

  access_log /var/log/socket/nginx.socket.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/socket/nginx.socket.error.log;  

#  location / {
#       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
#       client_max_body_size 50M;
#       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#       proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
#       proxy_buffers 256 16k;
#       proxy_buffer_size 16k;
#       proxy_read_timeout 600s;
#       proxy_pass https://backend;
#  }

  location ~ /socketcluster/ {     
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  
   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_read_timeout 30s;
       proxy_pass https://backend;
  } 

}
```

Backend main.js

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2)),
    SocketCluster = require('socketcluster').SocketCluster,
    fs = require('fs');

 require('./modules/cron');

var socketCluster = new SocketCluster({
    workers: Number(argv.w) || 1,
    brokers: Number(argv.b) || 1,
    port: Number(argv.p) || 1337,
    authKey: 'hasudiashdjuXDDDDDDDDDDDDDD',
    appName: argv.n || null,
    workerController: __dirname + '/worker.js',
    brokerController: __dirname + '/broker.js',
    socketChannelLimit: 100,
    rebootWorkerOnCrash: argv['auto-reboot'] != false,
    pingTimeout: 10000,
    pingInterval: 4000,
    authAlgorithm: 'HS256',
    allowClientPublish: false,
    wsEngine: 'uws',
    protocol: 'https',
    protocolOptions: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem')
    }
});
```

frontend конектится к socket.domain.ru:1337

Почему нет конекта? Прошу вашей помощи!  Как правильно настроить конфиг Nginx?

Comment: а бекенд поднят-то? с локалхоста можно до бекенда достучаться?

Comment: бэкенд поднят вроде! Но он почему-то на IP 0 :::1337

Comment: Скриншот netstat -lpn.  http://s019.radikal.ru/i640/1711/7b/0624aec474f3.png

Comment: думаю, в этом `/etc/hosts` виноват. я бы проэкспериментировал с `host: '127.0.0.1'` при создании сервера

Comment: не понимаю как с этим экспериментировать :( при создании серверу некуда вписывать IP

Comment: в документации https://socketcluster.io/#!/docs/api-socketcluster написано   `// Lets you specify a host name to bind to - Defaults to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)` `host: null,`

Comment: Хост поставили, всеравно нет конекта между backend - frontend

Comment: https://vk.com/photo193056122_456242180

Comment: ну, снова те же вопросы:  
а бекенд поднят-то? с локалхоста можно до бекенда достучаться (телнетом, например)?

Comment: Вот если бы узнать как тельнетом дюстучпть в бэк...

Comment: backend запущен но с локального остальные к нему нету коннекте.

Comment: а нетстат что говорит? вообще я вначале протупил, ведь в настройках upstream в nginx нужно было заменить `127.0.0.1` на `localhost`

Comment: После того как был добавлен host: в main.js стало показывать в netstat -lpn что нода на 127.0.0.1:1337

Comment: Но нету доступа к бэкенд даже командой. curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: http://127.0.0.1:1337" -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1" http://127.0.0.1:1337 а если заменить на https ругается на верификацию ssl сертификата.

Comment: Сейчас висит конект в netstat -lpn 0 :::1337 /node что то там... Это вроде ipv6 я не понимаю как тогда к нему должен подключается frontend